# Error with AJAX request in javascript and express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm a complete beginner to this. I have searched endlessly over the internet but I just cannot figure out the problem. Probably I'm making some basic conceptual mistake, so any help would be appreciated.

I want to take a simple form input using `javascript` or `jquery` and an `ajax` request. Here's the relevant code.

```
//JavaScript:

function sendMails(){

          console.log("This is executing");

        var data={
            first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            toArtists: $("#toArtists").val(),
            comments: $("#comments").val(),
            bcc_Emails: $("#bcc_Emails").val()
            };

          $.ajax({ 
           url: "/sendMailsToArtists",
           type: "POST",
           cache: false, 
           async: true,
           data: data,
           //data: $("commentform").serialize(),

           success: function(data){
              alert('Success!')
              console.log("This is executingggggg");
           }
           , 
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
               alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
           }
        });
      //return false;
   }
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" name="commentform" id="commentform">

  //Some fields
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right" id="send_btn" onclick="sendMails()">Send</button>

</form>
```

The URL is contained in a file called `app.js` which I run for the server.

The line `"This is executing"` gets printed on the console. And then the alert pops up with the message `"text status error, err"`. And then the page navigates to a URL which is something like `"http://localhost:3000/contactArtists?first_name=ohohoo&email=mallika13055%4…"`

Excuse me if it's something really basic.

EDIT:

Okay so I changed to `<button type = "button">`.

Here's the server side code:

```
app.post('/sendMailsToArtists', function (req, res){

  console.log(req.body);
});
```

The data gets printed on the terminal. Does this mean there's no error? Then why doesn't the success branch of the ajax request get executed?

EDIT 2:

It's resolved. res.send() does the job.

Comment: You should use console.log instead of alert to inspect the err object

Comment: The problem is likely to be serverside. Can we look at that code, or at least what the server is receiving when you POST data? It's hard to know what happens between the POST getting sent out, and the redirect happening...

Comment: @StefanoOrtisi - yeah, fixed that.

Comment: @Sze-HungDanielTsui - posted. now there's no error, but no "success" either. And the page doesn't get redirected.

Comment: try printing `jqXHR.status`, `jqXHR.statusText`, and `jqXHR.responseXML` to console.log.

Comment: Okay, I added a `res.send()` statement after the current one in the `app.js` file and the success branch of the ajax function executed. So I guess it's fine now. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the edit, adding a `res.send()` after the `console.log(req.body)` on the server side does the job. The success branch of the ajax request gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

you are using submit button, which submits form so use `type='button'` it will work

```
<button type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right" id="send_btn" onclick="sendMails()">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have did correct ajax call in jquery. Assuming all value you want to pass to "sendMailsToArtists" method. Suppose you are running your application on http://localhost/youapp/method. This is you server URL. While doing ajax post call, in URL parameter you have set  url:"/sendMailsToArtists" so this path is not readable to server. fist of all you have to consider to root path i.e **url:"../controllername/methodName"**

Here ".." stand root of application. Only this mistake you have did here. Please correct url parameter value according to you current application path.

You want to get correct idea of where you ajax call is going user web developer tool (enter f12 in chrome ) & open network tab. now perform you ajax call you can see to which url your request it going.

```
function sendMails(){

          console.log("This is executing");
        var data={

        first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        toArtists: $("#toArtists").val(),
        comments: $("#comments").val(),
        bcc_Emails: $("#bcc_Emails").val()
        };

      $.ajax({ 
       url: "../sendMailsToArtists",
       type: "POST",
       cache: false, 
       async: true,
       data: data,
       //data: $("commentform").serialize(),

       success: function(data){
          alert('Success!')
          console.log("This is executingggggg");
       }
       , 
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
           alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
       }
    });
```

}

This may helps you.

Comment: this is not causing a problem as far as i can see. in my current code, the `console.log(req.body)` statement is getting executed, which means the URL is fine i guess.